# Alternative coloured table rows in css

Tags: css, html-table, background-color

I'm trying to modify our Cruise Control .NET system to change the background colour on alternative rows of the build status page.

The cruisecontrol.css file contains the following for the build status table.

```css
tr.buildStatus table
    {
     margin-left: 20px;
    }
    tr.buildStatus td
    {
     font-style: italic;
     border: none;
     text-align: left;
    }
    
    
    /* Adding this affects ALL tables and looks bad */
    tr.buildStatus:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
    tr.buildStatus:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
    
    /* I tried this, but it didn't affect the table */
    tr.buildStatus:nth-child(even) { background: #CCC }
    tr.buildStatus:nth-child(odd) { background: #FFF }
```

I'm a little confused with how selectors work.  How do I get it to apply to the BuildStatus table?

Comment: We need to see the html of the table to be sure. Right now the styles (the last 4 look the same, btw) are being added to rows that have class `buildStatus`.

Comment: So you have a table inside of a table? It's impossible to answer this without your HTML, though the pseudo-selector `:nth-child` applies to the *element*, **not** the children. In your example you're applying it to `.buildStatus` itself, which should be the class on the *rows*.

Comment: try `tr.buildStatus:nth-child(even) { background-color: #CCC }
    tr.buildStatus:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #FFF }`

Comment: I've tried copying relevant HTML but it's too big and complicated.  It's a very old school build system I'd love to chuck away but it's not my decision to make.

Comment: Turns out the classname was wrong.  I got it working with wazz's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `table`

```
table tr.buildStatus:nth-child(even) { background: #CCC; }
```

Comment: This works, but I had the wrong classname.  Once the classname was corrected it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```css
.buildStatus {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.buildStatus tr th, .buildStatus tr td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

.buildStatus tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ccc
}
```

```html
<table class="buildStatus">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Johnson</td>
    <td>67</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have added HTML to show how css selectors works. You can just adjust according to your html. For reference go through the link below. Hope it'd help!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors